# Problem running a small script as cron job

Tags: php, linux, cron

I am problem scheduling and running a script through cron job. I am on linux (ubuntu), it is a VPS.
What I am doing is I have put this line in crontab file that is here: /etc/crontab
I wrote:

```
*/15 *    * * *   www-data  php /var/www/abs/phpscript.php
```

I have given 777 to the file and after writing above in crontab , I run command:

```
crontab crontab
```

Then after almost some time I got the mail in my /var/mail/username file that says: /bin/sh: root: not found

So I am unable to understand what is the problem.

I also run phpinfo and it shows the third variable as APACHE that probably means that PHP is running as apache module.

Please tell what can be the possible solution.

thanks in advance to every one who will try to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you edited `/etc/crontab`, you should **re-read the warning** at the top of the file:

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.
```

Running `crontab(1)` on the `/etc/crontab` file probably contaminated the root *user's* `crontab(5)` file (the one stored in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/`). I suggest running `crontab -e` *as root* to edit the crontab file, and remove all the entries that are identical to the entries from `/etc/crontab`. (*Maybe* you just contaminated your own personal `crontab(5)` -- if `crontab -e` as root didn't show anything, run `crontab -e` under your own personal account and see if the system-wide entries were duplicated into your own `crontab(5)`.)

I don't know what file you ran `chmod 777` on, but that was probably unnecessary. You really should set your permissions to be as strict as possible to confine the results of malicious attacks or unintentional mistakes.

Comment: thanks but can you tell that where I can add this? I am a developer but have never schedule a cron job

Comment: @Hafiz, heh, sorry :) Most of my post was about _cleaning up_ the results of `crontab crontab` -- I assumed that you had actually correctly entered the commands into your `/etc/crontab` file and that there was nothing left to do there -- it is probably working fine, if you can just call `php /var/www/abs/phpscript.php` as `www-user` and everything works -- and that the error messages you were getting were related to a _duplicate_ set of `crontab` entries.

Comment: ok thanks now I am using different file and it is working fine. thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can try also to run it using  "wget -q -O"

or

```
*/15 * * * * lynx -dump "url"  > /dev/null
```

Wget examples:

```
*/15 * * * * wget -O /dev/null 'http://www.mydomain.com/document.php?&user=myuser&password=mypass' >/dev/null
```

If you need to post data you can use

--post-data "login=user&password=pass"

```
*/15 * * * * wget -O /dev/null 'http://www.mydomain.com/document.php?&user=myuser&password=mypass' --post-data 'foo=bar' >/dev/null
```

Comment: I am using www-data as my user so should I leave the username if I will try the command you told, and can you please tell the usage of "wget -q -O" , I saw it on web but don't know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

You are running a crontab as a user, which means you can't specify the user in the cron.

The template you borrowed your example from was for a system (root) cron.

Remove the username and try again.